# vb.net program not writing to Oracle, but no errors

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, oracle, oracle10g, drivers

I have a vb.net program that I'm converting from compiling in VS2005 to VS2008, and also moving to run on a different server.

This works:
vb.net 2005, running on a server with Oracle 10 drivers, writing to Oracle 10g database.

vb.net 2008 compiled as x86, running in debug on my local Win7 machine with Oracle 11 drivers, writing to Oracle 10g database.

This does not work:
vb.net 2008 compiled as x86, running on server with Oracle 10 or 11 drivers, writing to Oracle 10g database

The problem is that the program doesn't write anything, but it also doesn't return any errors.  It claims that it works fine.  The following code does not provide any errors when it runs.

This code sets the connection information (and I just noticed that it does NOT have a try catch here)

```
Private Sub SetConnectionToDB(ByRef oCMD As OracleCommand)
    Dim connectionString As String
    connectionString = My.Settings.ImportDataConnectionString
    Dim OraDBConnection As OracleConnection
    OraDBConnection = New OracleConnection(connectionString)

    oCMD.Connection = OraDBConnection
    oCMD.CommandType = CommandType.Text
End Sub
```

and then the following code writes the data.  No error occurs here, and after this point, a log is written successfully, so it does go past this point.

**EDIT:** I added a print to log of the insert command, after the ExecuteNonQuery statement below.  It printed to the log the records that I wish would be inserted, if I could only figure out the problem.

```
    Private Sub StoreDataInDB(ByVal insertCommand As String, ByRef oCMD As OracleCommand, ByRef logStream As StreamWriter)
    ' Connect to the Oracle database and send the insert statement
    Try
        oCMD.CommandText = insertCommand
        oCMD.Connection.Open()
        oCMD.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception
        'send error to a log
        'MsgBox(ex.Message())
        logStream.WriteLine("----------- Error occurred inserting data to Oracle -----------")
        logStream.WriteLine(insertCommand)
        logStream.WriteLine()
        logStream.WriteLine(ex.Message())
        logStream.WriteLine()
    Finally
        oCMD.Connection.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

The one thing I'm still unsure about (I'm waiting for a reply), is my connection string.  I don't see that my Data Source is identified on my pc, and I'm not sure if it is defined on the servers, or where.  My connection string is something like the following:

```
connectionString="Data Source=OracleDB;User ID=UserIDHere;Password=PasswordHere;Unicode=True;Persist Security Info=True;"
```

The Insert command is a string of the format

```
 "Insert into user.table (" & _
  "FieldName1, " & _
  "FieldName2, " & _
  "FieldName3) VALUES (" & _
   Value1 & ", " & _
   Value2 & ", " & _
   Value3 & ")"
```

Are there any ideas for what direction to look, what to try?

**EDIT**: I've compiled as x86 and x64 (it's a 64 bit server).  I've asked for the return value on the oCMD.ExecuteNonQuery and it returns 1 as it pretends to write 1 record.  I've messed with the connection string and tried various options.  Sometimes it will fail, but when it does work, it still fails silently.  The oracle driver on the server is OraClient10g_64.

Comment: Check your connection string based on how Oracle is setup using [the examples here](http://connectionstrings.com/oracle). You should also look into using SQL Parameters rather than direct string injection of values. As long as you use direction inject, you are _probably_ missing quotes within the SQL command if any of those values are strings (quotes used by SQL and _not_ by VB.NET).

Comment: make sure by the connection string that it is talking to the database that you think it's talking to.

Comment: @Bala R - I used the same connection string on my pc, and it did write to the database, which is why I'm checking to see how the data source is defined on the server.

Comment: @pickypig - I will check that link, thank you.  The data being entered is closely validated long before it gets to the insert command, so there is no sql injection nor extra quotes by this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@BalaR had the right idea -- the connection string is defined in app.config, and I was doing a clean and rebuild.  However, there is an autogenerated file in My Project called Settings.Designer.vb, and that is not regenerated on a clean.  It had a connection string pointing to a different database.

On my pc, in debug mode or not, it used the settings from app.config.  On the server, it used the other connection string, and was writing to a different database.

That autogenerated file needed to be regenerated (double-click My Project, choose Settings tab, and it will rebuild itself), so that it matches the app.config file.